Где писать на SystemVerilog
Начал изучать книгу "Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера". В 4 главе описываются языки описания аппаратуры и мой вопрос звучит так: в какой среде я с ними познакомиться, где бы мог написать самостоятельно что нибудь и посмотреть на результат?

Поищите в гугле по запросу verilog simulator
